# PostgreSQL order by TSRange

Tags: postgresql

I think the question is pretty self explanatory, I've been learning about Postgres TSRange column type, but I've not been able to find an example of how you can order by it... How do you order by a TSRange, or specifically the lower bound?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are range functions described in [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-range.html#RANGE-FUNCTIONS-TABLE).

```
SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY lower(range_column);
```

Comment: Bah. I read that page a few times and managed to just space over that table, thanks for spelling it out!